# css: alignment issue with image and header

Tags: html, css

I'm having problems trying to align an image with a header inside a navigation menu. Ideally, everything should be align at the bottom. I have created a jsfiddle to reproduce the issue:

http://jsfiddle.net/graphicsxp/j2t9R/

```
        <nav style="float: left">
            <ul class="menu">
                <li>
                    <a href="index.html" class="logo">
                        <img src="img/logo.png" alt="" class="brand logo_def" width="125" height="39" /></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <h4 >Sam</h4>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="clear"></div>

        </nav>
        <nav>
            <ul class="menu">
                <li class="current-menu-parent"><a href="javascript:void(0)">ACCUEIL</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">PAGES</a>

                </li>                   
            </ul>
            <!-- .menu -->
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

as is:

[image: current state]

to be:

[image: to be]

Comment: What should it look like?

Comment: @Sam what exactly do you want can you post the image of your desired result....

Comment: show us a foto how should it look like

Comment: ok, I've added images of what it looks like now, and of what I want it to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem using your code, and honestly I couldn't tell you what I changed because there is way to much code going on for such a simple task. [Here it is anyway](http://jsfiddle.net/j2t9R/3/)

I also took the liberty of making a *new* one, showing how simple your code [*could* look](http://jsfiddle.net/9a5Wr/)

Simple, clean, easy to read. All done with one `<div>`, and an unordered list.

Simplifying your code and making it easy to read should be a primary goal in coding no matter what, but it also helps users answer your questions quicker, easier, and better help you with questions you have.

Comment: I agree with everything you said. The thing is that this code is from a website template that I've bought. I've done that because I don't have the time to build my own website from scratch. Making the changes you've made do solve my problem, but it breaks many other things. Thanks for helping though.

Comment: Gotta love temates. Glad I could be of some help though

Answer (score 0):

Temp fix can be as:

add css for h4 element.... better to give id and then add.

I have seen your fiddle, please put below code in your css

```
h4{
    margin-top:150px;
}
```

or

(Give id=hompageheaderUserName to h4 of sam)

```
h4#hompageheaderUserName
{
    margin-top:150px;
}
```

Change width a/c to your need.

Screenshot from fiddle:

[image]

Comment: I did this originally but it caused problems on window resize, there was a 150px gap between the elements.